# Stop XML parsing after a specific number of entries

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

I am currently using Poco::XML to parse through a number of very large XML files using SAX. For some of those files I only need the first *n* number of entries. I was wondering if anyone can show me how to tell Poco::XML to cease parsing once I go over my threshold of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a pull parser and If I am looking at the correct library (I am a java developer) poco does support pull parsing. Look here http://pocoproject.org/blog/?p=322

If this is not the right library for you then you need to throw an exception that stops the parsing operation (may be SAXException when using standard SAX API) after parsing the number of records you want.

Ok, throwing an exception would stop the parsing according to the [api doc here](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.XML.XMLReader.html#26224)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.. I was also contemplating using the Exception approach, but was hoping for something else I might have missed. I guess I will throw an exception then.